# Capturing Persistent Relations in a Form

Tags: haskell, yesod

I have defined a one-to-many relationship in Persistent but could not figure out how to create a form that can take one of the foreign keys as input.  Simplifying my use case to something like this:

```
Person
  name String

Car
  personId PersonId 
  name Text
  type Text
```

Now when I try to generate a Form for Car, what should be the field type for personId? I tried something like this but get an error:

```
entryForm :: Maybe Car -> Form Car
entryForm car = renderDivs $ Car
    <$> areq   personIdField   "Person" Nothing
    <*> areq   textField   "Car Name" ( carName <$> car)
    <*> areq   textField  "Type" ( carType <$> car)
```

When I run the above I get the error:  `` Not in scope: `personIdField'. ``

I tried `intField` and it says:

```
Couldn't match expected type `KeyBackend
                                persistent-1.2.1:Database.Persist.Sql.Types.SqlBackend Person'
            with actual type `Text'
Expected type: Field
                 m0
                 (KeyBackend
                    persistent-1.2.1:Database.Persist.Sql.Types.SqlBackend Person)
  Actual type: Field m0 Text
In the first argument of `areq', namely `intField'
In the second argument of `(<$>)', namely
  `areq intField "Person" Nothing
```

Ideally I would like to populate a drop down of Person Names (if there are not too many) or have a free form text field (e.g., with autocomplete) when there are too many. Any suggestions on how I can get foreign key as an input from the user?

**Update**:

I tried using selectField as follows but not sure if I am doing this correctly. I still get an error. First I created a where statement to get personId:

```
 where
   personId = do  
       person <- runDB $ selectFirst [] [Asc PersonName] 
       case person of
           Just (Entity pId p) -> return pId
           -- Nothing             -> ???
```

and then I changed my first areq to

```
 <$> areq (selectField [("First", personId)]) "Person Name" Nothing
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use `selectField`

Comment: @Ankur could you please elaborate what you mean by it? I tried using selectField but still get a similar error. But then I am not really sure if I am using it properly. Also, how would this structure work, if I just want to take free form input from the user and then map it back to an ID later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to use selectField properly. This is what I ended up doing:

```
where
    people = do
        entities <- runDB $ selectList [] [Asc PersonName]
        optionsPairs $ map (\p -> (personName $ entityVal p, entityKey p)) entities
```

The form field became:

```
<$> areq   (selectField people) "Person Name" Nothing
```

I still have not figured out free form entry just yet but this is a good start.