# How can I show a <select> for a has many relationship in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent, yesod-forms

I have a simple one-to-many relationship, say something like this

```
Process
    name Text

Report
    time Text
    process ProcessId
```

I'd like to create a form for creating posts where I'll be able to select from a list of existing users. Something like this.

```
processOptions :: Handler (OptionList (KeyBackend SqlBackend Process))
processOptions = optionsPersist [] [Desc ProcessName] id

postForm = renderDivs $ Report
             <$> areq textField "Time" Nothing
             <*> areq (selectField processOptions) "Process" Nothing
```

The prolem is, that I can't just figure out how to properly use `selectField` together with `optionsPersist`. I've looked at the source code for clues, but I just can't figure out what to do with this.

The expected type of the `optionsPersist` seems to be `Handler (OptionList (KeyBackend SqlBackend Process))`, though what it actually returns is `Handler (OptionList (Entity Process))`. I'm not sure if I'm missing something, or if there's some unwrapping that needs to be done.

Here's the actual error message

```
Couldn't match type ‘Entity (ProcessGeneric SqlBackend)’
              with ‘KeyBackend SqlBackend Process’
Expected type: Handler (OptionList (KeyBackend SqlBackend Process))
  Actual type: HandlerT
                 App IO (OptionList (Entity (ProcessGeneric SqlBackend)))
```

*While there [is a question for a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778494/capturing-persistent-relations-in-a-form), I don't think this is a duplicate, as this question is about using `optionsPersist`, while the other question simply generates the options manually.*

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you're almost there. The problem doesn't seem to be in how you're calling `selectField` or `processOptions`. The issue is that the result of that call is going to be an `Entity Process`, whereas the second field in `Report` is an `ProcessId`. So you just need to use `fmap` (aka `<$>`) to convert. I believe the following will do it:

```
entityKey <$> (areq (selectField processOptions) "Process" Nothing)
```